# Get responses from External API need Login session

Tags: rest, laravel-5, guzzle

I want to get data from External API. but, I must login to get session before Getting data and I must Logout after get data

this is my code

```
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'Login_URL', [
        'json' => [
            "JSON param"
        ]
    ]);
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'Get_URL');
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'Logout_URL');
```

but I can only the first step (Login). and I getting error message in the second step to get data

```
Client error: `GET "Get_URL" ` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:{"message":"You are not logged in."}
```

how I can run all this code with login session on first step ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code for you to do login and logout session

```
$cookie_jar = tempnam("tmp", "cookie");
    //login
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => '_URL',
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING      => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS     => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT       => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=> true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION  => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR     => $cookie_jar,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    =>'{
            "name"      : "****",
            "password"  : "****",
            "company"   :  "****"
        }',
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json'),
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    //get data
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => '_URL',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => $cookie_jar
        )
    );
    $datapo = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    //logout
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => '_URL',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => '{   
            "name" : "****",
            "password" : "****",
            "company" :   "****"
        }',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => $cookie_jar
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```